# creating a new jplayer on image select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

i have this html5 div block:

```
    <div id="st_main">
      <img src="/artistes/david_merlo/David_Merlo_Solo_PosteaGalene_2011_Ulrike_Monso.jpg" alt="" class="st_preview" style="display:none;" />
      <div class="st_overlay"></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Les Artistes</a>
          <div class="sc_menu_wrapper">
            <div class="sc_menu">
              <a href="#" m4v="/artistes/diez/diez_demo.m4a" oga="/artistes/diez/diez_demo.ogg" mp3="/artistes/diez/diez_demo.mp3"><img src="/artistes/david_merlo/david_merlo_thumb.jpg" alt="/artistes/david_merlo/David_Merlo_Solo_PosteaGalene_2011_Ulrike_Monso.jpg"></a>
              <a href="#" m4v="/artistes/david_merlo/diez_demo.m4a" oga="/artistes/david_merlo/diez_demo.ogg" mp3="/artistes/david_merlo/diez_demo.mp3"><img src="/artistes/nicolas-dick/L'Embobineuse_avec_phil_niblock.jpg" alt="/artistes/nicolas-dick/concert_glazart_du_25_02.jpg"></a>
              <a href="#" m4v="/audio/01_Tribu.m4a" oga="/audio/01_Tribu.ogg" mp3="/audio/01_Tribu.mp3"><img src="/artistes/jean-luc_gergonne/jlgergonne_thumb.jpg" alt="/artistes/jean-luc_gergonne/jlgergonne.jpg"></a>
              <a href="#" m4v="/artistes/diez/diez_demo.m4a" oga="/artistes/diez/diez_demo.ogg" mp3="/artistes/diez/diez_demo.mp3"><img src="/artistes/diez/diez_130x195.jpeg" alt="/artistes/diez/diez.jpeg"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="zen">
        <span class="player"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="progress"></span>
        <span class="buffer"></span>
        <span class="drag"></span>
        <div class="button">
          <span class="icon play"></span>
          <span class="icon pause"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and my javascript code is as follows:

```
function tsunamiClient() {
  var self = this;
  var width = $(".menu").width();
  //the ul element 
  var $list = $('.menu');
  //the current image being shown
  var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');

  //let's load the current image 
  //and just then display the navigation menu
  $('<img>').load(function(){
    $currImage.fadeIn(3000);
    //slide out the menu
    setTimeout(function(){
      $list.animate({'left':'0px'},500);
    },
    1000);
    }).attr('src',$currImage.attr('src'));

    this.init = function() {
      self.sliderMenu();
    };

  // Slider Menu
  this.sliderMenu = function() {
    /* function to make the thumbs menu scrollable */
    //clicking on a thumb, replaces the large image
    $list.find('.sc_menu img').bind('click',function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');
        $this.insertBefore($currImage);



        $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
          $(this).remove();
        });
        }).attr('src',$this.attr('alt'));
      }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
      }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});
      });

    //the loading image
    function buildThumbs($elem){
      var $wrapper = $elem.next();
      var $menu = $wrapper.find('.sc_menu');
      var inactiveMargin     = 150;
      /* move the scroll down to the
      beggining (move as much as the height of the menu) */
      $wrapper.scrollTop($menu.outerHeight());

      /* when moving the mouse up or down, the wrapper moves (scrolls) up or down */
      $wrapper.bind('mousemove',function(e){
        var wrapperHeight = $wrapper.height();
        var menuHeight = $menu.outerHeight() + 2 * inactiveMargin;
        var top = (e.pageY - $wrapper.offset().top) * (menuHeight - wrapperHeight) / wrapperHeight - inactiveMargin;
        $wrapper.scrollTop(top+10);
      });
    }

    var stacktime;

    $('.menu li > a').bind('mouseover',function () {
      var $this = $(this);

      buildThumbs($this);

      var pos = $this.next().find('a').size();
      var f = function(){
        if(pos==0) clearTimeout(stacktime);
        $this.next().find('a:nth-child('+pos+')').css('visibility','visible');
        --pos;
      };
      /* each thumb will appear with a delay */
      stacktime = setInterval(f , 50);
    });

    /* on mouseleave of the whole <li> the scrollable area is hidden */
    $('.menu li').bind('mouseleave',function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      clearTimeout(stacktime);
      $this.find('.sc_menu').css('visibility','hidden').find('a').css('visibility','hidden');
      $this.find('.sc_menu_wrapper').css('visibility','hidden');
    });

    /* when hovering a thumb, change its opacity */
    $('.sc_menu a').hover(
      function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('img')
        .stop()
        .animate({'opacity':'1.0'},400);
      },
      function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('img')
        .stop()
        .animate({'opacity':'0.3'},400);
      }
    );
  };
  // jPlayer
  this.tsunamiPlayer = function(music) {
    ///init screen
    var player = $(".zen .player");
    var no_of_tracks = $(".sc_menu a").length;
    player.jPlayer({
      ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
          m4a: m4a,
          mp3: mp,
          oga: oga
        });
      },
      swfPath: "/js/jplayer/Jplayer.swf",
      supplied: "m4a, mp3, oga"         
    });
    // preload, update, end
    player.bind($.jPlayer.event.progress, function(event) {    

      var audio = $('.zen audio').get(0);
      var pc = 0;    

      if ((audio.buffered != undefined) && (audio.buffered.length != 0)) {
        pc = parseInt(((audio.buffered.end(0) / audio.duration) * 100), 10); 
        displayBuffered(pc);
        //console.log(pc);
        if(pc >= 99) {
          //console.log("loaded");
          $('.zen .buffer').addClass("loaded");
        }  
      }        

    });
    //player.bind($.jPlayer.event.loadeddata, function(event) {    
      //$('.zen .buffer').addClass("loaded");    
    //});

    player.bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) { 
      var pc = event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute;
      if (!dragging) { 
        displayProgress(pc);
      }
    });

    player.bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function(event) {   
      $('.zen .circle').removeClass( "rotate" );
      $(".zen").removeClass( "play" );
      $('.zen .progress').css({rotate: '0deg'});
      status = "stop";
    });

    // play/pause

    $(".zen .button").bind('mousedown', function() {
      // not sure if this can be done in a simpler way.
      // when you click on the edge of the play button, but button scales down and doesn't drigger the click,
      // so mouseleave is added to still catch it.
      $(this).bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
        onClick();
      });
    });

    $(".zen .button").bind('mouseup', function() {
      $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
      onClick();
    });

    function onClick() {

      if(status != "play") {
        status = "play";
        $(".zen").addClass( "play" );
        player.jPlayer("play");
      } else {
        $('.zen .circle').removeClass( "rotate" );
        $(".zen").removeClass( "play" );
        status = "pause";
        player.jPlayer("pause");
      }
    };

    // draggin

    var clickControl = $('.zen .drag');

    clickControl.grab({
      onstart: function(){
        dragging = true;
        $('.zen .button').css( "pointer-events", "none" );

      }, onmove: function(event){
        var pc = getArcPc(event.position.x, event.position.y);
        player.jPlayer("playHead", pc).jPlayer("play");
        displayProgress(pc);

      }, onfinish: function(event){
        dragging = false;
        var pc = getArcPc(event.position.x, event.position.y);
        player.jPlayer("playHead", pc).jPlayer("play");
        $('.zen .button').css( "pointer-events", "auto" );
      }
    });    

    // functions

    function displayProgress(pc) {
      var degs = pc * 3.6+"deg"; 
      $('.zen .progress').css({rotate: degs});
    }
    function displayBuffered(pc) {
      var degs = pc * 3.6+"deg"; 
      $('.zen .buffer').css({rotate: degs});
    }

    function getArcPc(pageX, pageY) { 
      var    self    = clickControl,
      offset    = self.offset(),
      x    = pageX - offset.left - self.width()/2,
      y    = pageY - offset.top - self.height()/2,
      a    = Math.atan2(y,x);  

      if (a > -1*Math.PI && a < -0.5*Math.PI) {
        a = 2*Math.PI+a; 
      } 

      // a is now value between -0.5PI and 1.5PI 
      // ready to be normalized and applied               
      var pc = (a + Math.PI/2) / 2*Math.PI * 10;   

      return pc;
    }
  }; 
  // end jPlayer
  // Initialise  
  this.init();
};


var tsunamiClient;

jQuery(function() {
  tsunamiClient = new tsunamiClient();
});​
```

this is what i have so far http://jsfiddle.net/aqoon/VUGL8/

it doesn't work as i want to be able to have the functionality so that when a user comes to the page and if they click on the play button for the jPlayer to play the music that corresponds to the image that is being displayed. and similarly if a user selects an image from the 'sc_menu' this updates the image in the  and also creates a new jplayer instance.

i added this code just after the  $list.find('.sc_menu img').bind('click',function(){ var $this = $(this);

```
  var link = $this.parent();
  var music;
  title = link.text();
  mp = link.attr("mp3");
  oga = link.attr("oga");
  m4a = link.attr("m4a");
  m4v = link.attr("m4v");
  ogv = link.attr("ogv");
  webmv = link.attr("webmv");
  poster = link.attr("poster");
  music = {
    title: title,
    mp: mp,
    oga: oga,
    m4a: m4a,
    ogv: ogv,
    webmv: webmv,
    poster: poster,
  }
  self.tsunamiPlayer(music);
```

and this does binds the data to the jplayer but when i change the image it does not update.

any advice on making this work so that:

1. on page display the initial jplayer loads the music files that correspond with artist image
2. when a user clicks on an thumbnail image from the menu the jplayer music files are updated accordingly.

any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

fixed, you can see the changes https://github.com/AssociationTsunami/tsunami/commit/7773a3a3308ec3b18eab0fa4c9731ea4e7eaf443